# What was the favor Brovada mentioned in the Chimera Ant Arc?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In the Chimera Ant Arc, Reina and Brovada return home and Brovada says he did it for a favor. What was the favor and who did he do it for?

Comment: You might want to be more specific about which episode/chapter/scene this happened in.

Answer (score 1):

Ikalgo (the octopus) had a chance to kill him when they were beneath the palace, but couldn't bring himself to do it. It was never clear if they actually had this discussion but I'm guessing bringing Reina home was returning the favor for not killing him. That's what the flash back showed as he said he returned the favor, too.